# CONSULTA SQL AGRUPANDO POR CODIGO Y FECHA

Tags: mysql

Buenos días solicito ayuda para realizar lo siguiente: tengo la siguiente db
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
y lo que quiero es que me carge en un datagrind el ultimo registro con la fecha más reciente por bahia es decir en el caso del codigo ACN y l abahia AE5 se muestre lo siguiente:

```
ACN 2019-05-29 15:50:32 TESTFINAL AE5 ENSAMBLE....
FET 2019-03-25 12:12:34 TESTFINAL BRP ....
ACN 2019-07-03 14:17:27 TESTFINAL BE4 ......
```

Comment: Y que intentaste? porque suena a un simple group by...

Comment: Cierto, comparte lo que intentaste y cual fue el resultado. a simple vista, lo que me imagino es ordernar por fecha y despues agrupar por bahia

Comment: intente con esto: INSERT INTO `kandon`(`Codigo`, `Time`, `OS`, `Bahia`, `Etapa`, `Tecnico`, `Ayudante_1`, `Ayudante_2`) VALUES ('COM', '2019-12-25 18:18:10.608317', 'IBS000837', 'BD3', 'Desensamble y Evaluacion', 'Guillermo Rocha', 'Javier Hernandez', 'NA'    SELECT `Codigo`, Max(`Time`), `OS`, `Bahia`, `Etapa`, `Tecnico`, `Ayudante_1`, `Ayudante_2` FROM kandon GROUP BY Bahia ORDER BY Max(`Time`) DESC

Comment: pero no me trae el valor insertado

Answer (score 0):

Tal como te dice algún comentario, a no ser que haya un requerimiento oculto, se trata de un simple `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT CODIGO, OS, BAHIA, ETAPA, Tecnico, MAX(Time)
FROM Tabla
GROUP BY CODIGO, OS, BAHIA, ETAPA, Tecnico
```

Comment: gracias por sus respuestas lo que pasa es que con ese query me marca esto CODIGO OS BAHIA ETAPA Tecnico MAX(Time)  
ACN  SAL001016  AD3  Recepcion e Inventario  Guillermo Rocha  2021-10-22 23:05:00.371677 pero hice un insert donde el codigo le puse COM no ACN y si me trae los datos actualiazdos menos el CODIGO porque me trae ACN